# x86-64 assembly pointer variable implementation in external memory

Tags: variables, pointers, assembly, x86-64

When on move address pointer from cpu register to external memory the address value change with apparent erroneous signed extension

Assembly Code:

```
    .section .data
argc:   .quad  0
        .section .bss
argv:   .space  8   # pointer variable definition
    .section .text
_start:
    .global _start
    movq (%rsp),%rax    #arguments number
    movq %rax,argc
    movq 8(%rsp),%rdi       #string address of first argument of command line
    movq %rdi,argv          #pointer variable initialization
```

GDB debugger stepping execution:

```
(gdb) p /a $rdi
$1 = 0x7fffffffe335
(gdb) p /a argv
$2 = 0xffffffffffffe335
```

The address 0x7fffffffe335 has the MSB to zero ¿ Why the argv value is not equal and has the MSB to one? ¿How can I implemented a variable pointer at external memory?

Thanks in advance

C.A. Mayoz

Comment: What the freak is wrong with GAS?? Nasm (using intel syntax) would have handled this just fine.

Comment: Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Canonical_form_addresses -- it's not just the msb that is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory contents are just fine, you are using gdb wrong. Since you are not providing debug info for the `argv` variable, gdb assumes it is an integer and on printing it as address it will be sign extended. If you examine the memory using for example `x/a &argv` or `x/8xb &argv` you will see all the bytes are there.